# How to put a 'grid' (for example dividing the x-y plane into bins) on an image to calculate mean of the z-values in every bin and plot as a heatmap?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, bin

My aim:

I have x, y and z values as arrays. For example:

```
x=np.array([10,2,-4,12,3,6,8,14])
y=np.array([5,5,-6,8,20,10,2,2])
z=np.array([4,6,10,40,22,14,20,8])
```

I want to plot a heatmap where the z-values will act as the intensity or 'weight' for every pair of (x,y) and the axes will be x and y values. So, my plot will be on a x-y plane. I want to lay a 'grid' on top of my plot by dividing my x-y plane into bins and then calculate the mean of the z-values within every bin and use that mean  value as my color or intensity for that bin. I also want to make another plot but there I want to plot the variance of z-values as the intensity within the bins.

What I have done:

I coded it the following way but I think I am misinterpreting things..I don't think I understand bins etc well (I am new to programming).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=np.array([10,2,-4,12,3,6,8,14])
y=np.array([5,5,-6,8,20,10,2,2])
z=np.array([4,6,10,40,22,14,-20,8])

# Bin the data onto a 2x2 grid
# Have to reverse x & y due to row-first indexing
zi, yi, xi = np.histogram2d(y, x, bins=(2,2), weights=z, normed=False)
counts, _, _ = np.histogram2d(y, x, bins=(2,2))

#to get mean divide by counts

zi = zi / counts
print(zi)

zi = np.ma.masked_invalid(zi)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc=ax.pcolormesh(xi, yi, zi, edgecolors='black')
sct = ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=200) #shows the points in the bins 
fig.colorbar(sc)
ax.margins(0.05)

plt.show()
```

Where I am stuck:

I am not even sure if the above code is doing the right thing. So, feel free to forget it and advise me on any other standard way of solving this problem.
With the above code I get a plot where the axes limits are determined by the given dataset automatically but I want to keep my axes constant at `xmin=-20,xmax=20,ymin=-20,ymax=20`.
Also, I am not sure how to manipulate the z-values within the bins to calculate other statistical quantities like variance or standard deviation etc.

EDIT: so, I have got some better code that gives the mean z values in bins and plot using `np.histogram2d` and the I can set the axes etc to my liking now but using this gives H as the sum of values in bins and I can get the mean from that but not other statistical quantities like variance. I wanted a way to code this so that I can have access to the values in the bin and I can calculate variance of those and use that result as the weight/intensity of the heatmap.

I am attaching the plot for mean z in bins.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.array([10,2,4,12,3,6,8,14])
y=np.array([5,5,6,8,20,10,2,2])
z=np.array([4,6,10,40,22,14,20,8])

x_bins = np.linspace(0, 20, 3)
y_bins = np.linspace(0, 20, 3)

H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins = [x_bins, y_bins], weights = z)
H_counts, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins = [x_bins, y_bins])

print(H)
H1 = H/H_counts
print(H1)

plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")

plt.imshow(H1.T, origin='lower',  cmap='RdBu',
            extent=[xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]])
plt.colorbar().set_label('mean z', rotation=270)
```

[image: here's the plot for mean z]

EDIT 2: When I use stats for standard deviation I get the following plot

[image: std plot]

The deep red bin on the top right is actually empty and has no z values so I want the standard deviation to be 'Nan' instead of being assigned a value of 0. How can I do that?

My code for this plot is:

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.array([10,2,4,12,3,6,8,14])
y=np.array([5,5,6,8,20,10,2,2])
z=np.array([4,6,10,40,22,14,20,8])

x_bins = np.linspace(0, 20, 3)
y_bins = np.linspace(0, 20, 3)

H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins = [x_bins, y_bins], weights = z)

#mean = stats.binned_statistic_2d(x,y,z,statistic='',bins=[x_bins,y_bins])
#mean.statistic
std = stats.binned_statistic_2d(x,y,z,statistic='std',bins=[x_bins,y_bins])
#std.statistic
#print(std.statistic)
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.imshow(std.statistic.T, origin='lower',  cmap='RdBu',
            extent=[xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]])
#plt.clim(0, 20)
plt.colorbar().set_label('std z', rotation=270)
```

Comment: Maybe seaborn's `sns.kdeplot(x=x,y=y,weights=z)`?

Comment: Hi @JohanC, thanks for the suggestion but I have used stats.binned_statistic_2D to d it..I think it's working for mean, median but not for standard deviation. I have mentioned the issue in my edit 2 of my post. For some reason the empty bins are showing 0 std instead of 'Nan'...any idea how I can fix this? I tried numpy.ma.masked_invalid on my H but it didn't seem to help. Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The last 2 source fences seem to be duplicated. Can you edit the post to delete one?

Answer (score 0):

You data need to be interpolated on a regular grid since your computer do not know which is the `z` value where there is no value. Lukily there is already a function for that: `scipy.interpolate.griddata`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Dummy data
x=np.array([10,2,-4,12,3,6,8,14])
y=np.array([5,5,-6,8,20,10,2,2])
z=np.array([4,6,10,40,22,14,-20,8])

# Create a regular grid along x and y axis
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[x.min():x.max()+1, y.min():y.max()+1]

# Linear interpolation
# But you could also use a cubic interpolation or whatever you want/need
z_interpolated = griddata((x,y), z, (grid_x, grid_y), method='linear')

# Plot the result:
plt.imshow(z_interpolated, cmap='plasma')
```

And we obtain:

[image]

Noticed that there is no value on the image boundary because your spatial domain is not defined beyond the value contained in `x` and `y` so with a linear interpolation, your computer can not guess what should be the value beyond those points. So the heatmap is restricted to the convexhull formed by your points, anything else will be extrapolation.

**Edit:**

If you need to compute a bidimentionnal binned statistic you can use:

```
scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d()
```

In your case if we want to compute the variance and the mean:

```
from scipy import stats
std = stats.binned_statistic_2d(x,y,z,statistic='std',bins=[x_bins,y_bins])
mean = stats.binned_statistic_2d(x,y,z,statistic='mean',bins=[x_bins,y_bins])
```

Where `mean` is totally equivalent to your `H/H_counts`

Comment: Hi @obchardon, thanks but I don't think this is what I want...the y axis should start from the bottom not the other way round. Plus I want mean of z values in every bin to be the intensity of the bin and another plot for variance of z values in each bin to be intensity of the bin. I have edited my post to include a better code for getting mean but I needed a way to get the variance which I am unsure of.

Comment: Thanks @obchardon! I used stats for mean and median and  it works but when I used it for std deviation, the bin that was empty was given standard deviation of 0 but I want it to be filled with Nan (like it usually is in case of mean and median). Please check my edited post. How could I do that?